# Creating custom options for "List-item" option in Option Tree plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem, I need to change the default options for a “List-item” option in Option tree . Right now the default are “Title/Image/Link/Descriptions” .. I want to remove them and add my own. I have written this code:

```
      array(
    'id'          => 'academic_success_content',
    'label'       => 'Academic Success Content',
    'desc'        => 'Enter the academic success content. It will appear in the home page in list items format',
    'std'         => '',
    'type'        => 'list-item',
    'section'     => 'academic_perfomance',
     'settings'    => array( 
      array(
        'id'          => 'academic_success',
        'label'       => 'Academic Success',
        'type'        => 'textarea-simple',
      )
    )
  ),
```

But when I preview the themes options , the default list item "title" is still there and I only want to see the Academic Success textarea. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also suffered from the same situation.

And after that, I use the older version of "list-item" and "gallery".

This has **worked well.** `Ex: v2.4.6`

Answer (score 0):

Is the theme options page being included?

You'll need to reference it in your functions.php, something to the effect of:

```
require_once locate_template('/path-to-your/theme-options.php' );
```

Comment: i contacted the developer and he said that feature is impossible for now till later versions @jaechick